# Oracle / SQL Tuning Advisor

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, database-performance

Can an STA work on a query that is not even run once in the database? I mean, if it's not there in the cache, can SQL tuning advisor get some result for us?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Tuning Advisor can work on queries that have never been run before. I'm not sure what interface you're using, but the [DBMS_SQLTUNE package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SQLTUNE.html#GUID-666E61F4-E942-4334-8A7F-A5E7CAC0AB93) makes it easy to pass in the SQL text.

For example, let's create a simple table with no indexes:

```
--Create a simple table with no indexes.
create table table_missing_index(a number);

insert into table_missing_index
select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLE_MISSING_INDEX');
end;
/
```

Then pass in a query that could obviously benefit from an index:

```
--Create, execute, and display the tuning task.
declare
    v_task varchar2(64);
begin
    v_task := dbms_sqltune.create_tuning_task
    (
        sql_text => 'select a from table_missing_index where a = 1'
    );

    dbms_sqltune.execute_tuning_task(task_name => v_task);

    dbms_output.put_line('Task name: '||v_task);
end;
/
```

Grab the task name from the output, and plug it into this query to see the results:

```
select dbms_sqltune.report_tuning_task('TASK_362') from dual;
```

The output should look something like this:

```
GENERAL INFORMATION SECTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tuning Task Name   : TASK_362
Tuning Task Owner  : JHELLER
Workload Type      : Single SQL Statement
Scope              : COMPREHENSIVE
Time Limit(seconds): 1800
Completion Status  : COMPLETED
Started at         : 04/04/2021 14:26:15
Completed at       : 04/04/2021 14:26:15

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Schema Name   : JHELLER
Container Name: ORCLPDB
SQL ID        : 0g6v1x1c7kcjt
SQL Text      : select a from table_missing_index where a = 1

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FINDINGS SECTION (1 finding)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1- Index Finding (see explain plans section below)
--------------------------------------------------
  The execution plan of this statement can be improved by creating one or more
  indices.

  Recommendation (estimated benefit: 98.56%)
  ------------------------------------------
  - Consider running the Access Advisor to improve the physical schema design
    or creating the recommended index.
    create index JHELLER.IDX$$_016A0001 on JHELLER.TABLE_MISSING_INDEX("A");

... [removed rest of the large report] ...
```

Comment: hi jon how STA choose index creation,how it know its percentage benefit ?i have several queries in a busy database are slow , and sometimes the sta is able to choose a correct sql profile and index creation and somtimes it cannot, is there a way i can do some calculation or analysis to know which index is created ?i know a bit abot histograms and distinct values and query plan hash join and filters and things like that but i want to know how to choose the correct index for a query, If i a asked a question with example and informations can you help me to know the best way to choose an index ?

Comment: as for the queries plan yes i know about sql managment and baseline especially in OEM it can show me several hash plans where i can choose, and compare but the hashplan are not always there and not always generated. thats why i want to understand how STA works for index creation, or if i can do some statsistics calculation because the querys is not always in the cursor cash or awr

Comment: @Baalback Those are complicated questions that are probably based on proprietary details that only Oracle knows. Even people who spend most of their professional career trying to figure out how costing and indexes work probably couldn't give you a complete answer that wasn't the length of a book. The best most of us can do is understand what concepts we can, make educated guesses, and then refine the guesses depending on how they work.